# Interpreting gprof Output and Identifying This Eigen Function

Tags: c++, eigen, gprof

I just ran `gprof` to profile some code of mine. Here are the first few lines of the flat profile. More than 75% of the time is being used by the first function. What is that function? What is it telling me about how I'm misusing the Eigen library?

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
 75.16    368.61   368.61                             void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double> >(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double> const&)
```

Here's that function name in a little bit nicer formatting:

```
void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 
                                               Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 
                                               Eigen::internal::assign_op<double>      >(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>&, 
                                                                                         Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, 
                                                                                         Eigen::internal::assign_op<double> const&)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function assign one `MatrixXd` to another one:

```
MatrixXd a, b;
b = a;
```

Thus means that most of the time is spent copying matrices.

So make sure that you compiled with optimizations ON (`-O3`), otherwise your profiling results are meaningless. If so, then make sure you pass matrices by reference and not by value, be careful if you use `std::vector<MatrixXd>`, etc.

Comment: what do you mean "be careful if you use std::vector<MatrixXd>?" I use quite a lot of `std::vector`s

Comment: nevermind I'll look into it. something like this but for `MatrixXd`s (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html). This was very helpful; thanks very much

Comment: I was not referring to alignment issue, because those do not concern `MatrixXd` but rather about prohibitive copies. Make sure to use c++11 and properly use std::vector so that move-semantic takes place.